# entity manager find method gets failed to lazily initialize a collection of role error

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

In Spring noticing if I use the entity manager find method on a one to many and there are rows in the child then I get the failed to lazily initialize error.

here's the setup:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
... many lines not shown ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Child {
... many lines not shown ...
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Parent parent;
}

@Repository
@Transactional
public class ParentDao {
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;
      public List<Parent> parents() {
        return em.createQuery("select distinct p from Parent p left outer join fetch p.children order by p.id",Parent.class).getResultList();
      }

  public Parent find(Parent parent) {
  return em.find(Parent.class, parent.getId());
  }
}
```

if I call the dao

```
Parent p = parentService.find(new Parent(5));
```

ic

```
select parent0_.id as id1_1_0_, parent0_.name as name2_1_0_ from parent parent0_ where parent0_.id=?
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: demo.model.Parent.children, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

in log

if I put in the sin of fetch = FetchType.EAGER

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
```

I get the generated SQL as expected:

```
 select parent0_.id as id1_1_0_, parent0_.name as name2_1_0_, children1_.parent_id as parent_i4_0_1_, children1_.id as id1_0_1_, children1_.id as id1_0_2_, children1_.parent_id as parent_i4_0_2_, children1_.project as project2_0_2_, children1_.type as type3_0_2_ from parent parent0_ left outer join child children1_ on parent0_.id=children1_.parent_id where parent0_.id=?
Parent [id=5, name=p05, children=[id=5, project=c05a, parentId=5],[id=6, project=c05b, parentId=5],[id=7, project=c05c, parentId=5],[id=8, project=c05d, parentId=5]]
```

so far the only work-a-round seems to be to remove the fetch type of eager then in the find method of the dao do

```
  public Parent find(Parent parent) {
    return em.createQuery("select p from Parent p left outer join fetch p.children where p.id = :id order by p.id",Parent.class)
             .setParameter("id", parent.getId())     
             .getSingleResult();
  }
```

My question is: Anyway to use em.find without having to use the fetch type of eagar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without using FetchType Eager by making sure the code that calls `parent.getChildren` is executed inside a transaction.

If you use `@Transactional` annotation from Spring to mark transactional methods you should note that the annotation works only on public methods. On private, package or protected methods you won't get an exception but also no transaction will be created. If you need to annotate non-public methods (you probably don't really need to), consider using AspectJ.

If you still get the Lazy Init Exception, consider enabling the log messages around transaction handling, namely these packages: `org.springframework.orm.jpa`, `org.springframework.transaction`.

Comment: hum .. I see what u mean .. and makes clearer what is meant by "lazy".

Comment: Within the find method I placed LOGGER.info("size " + parent.getChildren().size()); and saw another SQL generated. it does allow me to use the em find method but I end up with another SQL being run. All things considered it probably makes more sense to use the HQL listed above. I guess using the em find method gets only the required row and lazily does not get all. The getChildren() wants that info so the SQL to get it is generated. Perhaps it is a bit to lazy for what I need to do. :)

Comment: That sounds about right, that is how lazy loading works getting the children only when needed (call of the `get` or `size` methods). Take a look here for example: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading